# How to pre-populate django forms at CreateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

how can i prepopulate fields in django forms at create an instance with the fields from my profile model. say if my Profile model has a `Charfield` residence and in the registration i named a certain user's residence as say 'Cairo', I would like to know how i can go to fill in a form say a `PostCreateForm` and have the residence of a user get auto filled with Cairo and also make it non-editable. Such that if a form is asking for Post body and residence of the owner of the post, this logged in user will be able to just enter the post body details and at the post details view, he can view his posts with his residence attached to them.
I have tried implementing the `form = PostForm(initial={"residence": "Cairo"})` kind of approach as per the documentation but i'm still getting it wrong.
I tried it in my Views and in my form definition but seems i did it wrong.
I need help on how i can implement this on the get requests of the `CreateView` or in the forms.py model definition.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is my `views.py` code

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'posts/post_create.html'
    model = Post
    form_class = PostCreateForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.profile = request.user.profile
            instance.save()
            return redirect(reverse('posts:all_posts'))
        else:  # return form
            form = PostCreateForm(request.POST)
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, })
```

Comment: You should post your view to have a better context of the issue.

Comment: I have edited and added the view.py file

Comment: I don't see any issues with the view, can you post the form